# Sharing React component logic between separate renders

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I want the logic of a component to be accessible to the render method of separate stateless components.

The reason is that the Desktop version of the app will use the same logic and class methods, but the presentation of it will be different.

```
class Logic {
  constructor() {
    this.greeting = 'Buongiorno'
  }

  showCats() {
    return 'Mittens and Puss'
  }
}

const Desktop = () => {
  return <div style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
    {this.showCats()}
    {this.greeting}
  </div>
}

const Mobile = () => {
  return <div style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>
    {this.greeting}
    {this.showCats()}
  </div>
}
```

So I am trying to 'glue' the class to the functional component.

Can I do this without passing props into the stateless component?

How can the stateless component access the methods and variables inside the `Logic` class?

I am aware I could make `Desktop` and `Mobile` stateful components that `extend` the `Logic` class but I am not sure that is the best thing to do.

Comment: It can be solved by using of "higher order component" approach that will wrap your stateless components with a class that will provide required logic to them

Comment: it seems like you know when you r on desktop and when on mobile? why don't you use this information (as a condition) in the render function of the class Logic?

Comment: @Flying what's a good starting point for writing a higher order component?

Comment: @alanbuchanan I've added example as an answer

Answer (score 1):

```
    function Logic(wrappedComponent) {
       showCats() {
        return 'Mittens and Puss'
      }
      return (
        <wrappedComponent
        greetings="Buongiorno"
        showCats=showCats

        >
        {this.props.children}
        <wrappedComponent />
     )

    }

    const Desktop = () => {
      return <div style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>
        {this.props.greeting}
        {this.props.showCats()}
      </div>
    }
   export default Logic(Desktop)

    const Mobile = () => {
      return <div style={{ fontSize: 15 }}>
        {this.props.greeting}
        {this.props.showCats()}
      </div>
    }
    export default Logic(Mobile)
```

Higher order components are generally used to keep common functionality among different components.read more about this here https://medium.com/@franleplant/react-higher-order-components-in-depth-cf9032ee6c3e#.do3h4kouk

Answer (score 1):

This task cab be solved by using "higher order component" approach. Your HoC can look like this:

```
"use strict";
import React, {Component} from "react";

const getDisplayName = (Component) => Component.displayName || Component.name || 'Component';

/**
 * Higher order component to inject logic into provided component
 */
export const withLogic = Component => {
    class WithLogic extends Component {
        //noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
        static displayName = `WithLogic(${getDisplayName(Component)})`;

        get logic() {
            if (!this._logic) {
                this._logic = new Logic();
            }
            return this._logic;
        }

        render() {
            return <Component {...this.props} />;
        }
    }

    return WithLogic;
};
```

and its use is a composition pattern, widely used in React:

```
export default withLogic(Mobile);
```